# DT white space when saving to HTML in R

Tags: r, dt

I'm using `DT` to build an HTML table and I keep having this massive white space and can't seem to sort out how to get the columns to strength the page. An additional side note is that my left column fix doesn't seem to be fixing when setting `scrollX = TRUE`.

Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = c(2:4),
                list(avg = mean, SD = sd))) %>%
  relocate(Species, before = "Sepal.Length") %>%
  datatable(filter = 'top',
            options = list(pageLength = 100,
                          autoWidth = TRUE,
                          scrollY = "800px",
                          scrollX= TRUE,
                          fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason isn't because of the datatable itself, it's because of the way that RStudio saves the file.

You can read about the sizingPolicy, as RStudio interprets it here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/NotebookHtmlWidgets.R

The best way I found to fix this is to set the table to an object and change the object. I couldn't find what I was looking for via datatable's constructs.

This method worked for me:

```
# Your code, but assigned to d
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

d <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = c(2:4),
                list(avg = mean, SD = sd))) %>%
  relocate(Species, before = "Sepal.Length") %>%
  datatable(filter = 'top',
            elementId = "dt",
            options = list(pageLength = 100,
                           autoWidth = TRUE,
                           scrollY = "800px",
                           scrollX= TRUE,
                           fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 0)))
```

This will set the table to as wide as your browser window and dynamically adjust if you change the browser window size.

```
d$sizingPolicy$browser$defaultWidth = "100%"
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. Any idea on why the `scrollX` wont freeze my left column?

Comment: This SO question answers that one! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623584/fixing-a-column-in-shiny-datatable-while-scrolling-right-does-not-work